# How to specify additional class in a code-block in quilljs

Tags: javascript, quill

When you insert a code-block in quilljs editor, on render the code block is wrapped with `<pre class="ql-syntax"></pre>`

Is there a way to add additional class so I can custom format the code block while rendering? For example I want to somehow specify a class say lang-javascript so on render it would look like this: `<pre class="ql-syntax lang-javascript"></pre>`

Answer (score 3):

Here's [a Quill Playground example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmXOyo) of something similar to what you're asking for.

## HTML

```
<div id="editor">
  <pre class="js">var hi = function() { return 'fun'; };</pre>
  <pre class="clj">let[hi #('fun')]</pre>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.lang-javascript {
  background-color:#ccf;
}
.lang-clojure {
  background-color: #fcc;
}
```

## Javascript

```
// Import Block (I think it's from parchment)
let Block = Quill.import('blots/block');

// Create a custom blot for Javascript
class JsBlot extends Block { 
  static create(url) {
    let node = super.create();
    // Attribute for output HTML
    node.setAttribute('class', 'ql-syntax lang-javascript');
    return node;
  }
}

JsBlot.blotName = 'js';
// Class to look for when parsing your input HTML
JsBlot.className = 'js';
// Tag to look for when parsing your input HTML
JsBlot.tagName = 'pre';
// Register your custom blot with quill.
Quill.register(JsBlot);

// Create another custom blot for Clojure
class CljBlot extends Block { 
  static create(url) {
    let node = super.create();
    node.setAttribute('class', 'ql-syntax lang-clojure');
    return node;
  }
}
CljBlot.blotName = 'clj';
CljBlot.className = 'clj';
CljBlot.tagName = 'pre';
Quill.register(CljBlot);

// Start Quill
var quill = new Quill('#editor');
```

## Result

```
<div class="ql-editor" contenteditable="true">
  <pre class="ql-syntax lang-javascript">var hi = function() { return 'fun'; };</pre>
  <pre class="ql-syntax lang-clojure">let[hi #('fun')]</pre>
</div>
```

The playground includes buttons.  Click on a block in the editor, then click a button to toggle the pre language style on and off.